# SQL Statements in Netbeans

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans

I am creating a program for a school project in Netbeans. I am connecting it to a Microsoft access database. I need help with my SQL statement within Netbeans, how do I instantiate the Date data type within the SQL statement that will be used to add new records into the database?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're using MySql you need this format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

```
String oldstring = "2011-01-18 00:00:00";
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(oldstring, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"));
```